# Form action not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, action

In one of my views form action suddenly stopped working. When I click on submit page stays the same.But my other forms on same domain are working fine. Then what is the problem with this form??
I am doing this in codeigniter. So what might be the reason behind this??

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action=<?php echo base_url()."index.php/controller_user/checker"; ?>  >
  <table width="100%" border="0" >
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="prj" style="display: none;">Enter Project:-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input  type="text" name="prname" required/>
              </div>
              <div id="project">Enter Project:-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <select class="prj_name" name="prj_name" id="prj_name" onchange="process(this.value)" tabindex="11" required>
                  <option selected="selected">Select Project</option>
                  <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM project  ORDER BY prj_id DESC";
                    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
                    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
                      foreach ($query->result() as $row){
                        $projectName= $row->prj_name;
                        $projectID=$row->prj_id;
                        echo '<option value="'.$projectID.'">'.$projectName.'</option>';
                      }//end of for loop
                      echo '<option value="'.'0'.'">'.'New Project'.'</option>';
                    } 
                  ?>
                </select>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

This is my controller_user/checker

```
  function checker()
   {

   $projectname=$_POST['prj_name'];

        if($projectname=='0')
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload('layout');
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["layout1"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/" . $_FILES["layout1"]
  ["name"]);
            $file="uploads/".$_FILES["layout1"]["name"];
            $this->model_user->add_user_case1($file);

        }
        else
        { 
            $phase_name=$_POST['phase_name'];
            //$layout=$_POST['layout'];
             if($phase_name=='0') 
             {
                $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload('layout');
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["layout"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/" . $_FILES["layout"

    ]["name"]);
            $file="uploads/".$_FILES["layout"]["name"];

  /*$sql=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO phase (layout) VALUES ('$file')");*/
                $this->model_user->add_user_case2($projectname,$file);

             }
             else
             {
                 $plan_name=$_POST['plan_name'];

                if($plan_name=='0' )
                {



                    $this->model_user->add_user_case3($phase_name);

                }
                else{
                    $this->model_user->add_user_case4($plan_name);

                }
             }

        }

         echo '<script>alert("data registered successfully");</script>';
        redirect ('controller_search','refresh');

     }
```

Comment: can you show `controller_user/checker` code?

Comment: it's not my all form code.I just copy paste one part of it to explain

Comment: @LLL see my edit above

Comment: please check if any other form tag is there before this form and check for proper closing of form tag

Comment: I think you can use `error_log` to write post log at beginning checker method , and why don't you use ci input `$this->input->post()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here

```
<div id="prj" style="display: none;">
```

remove display none and try it with, it displayed `none` inside it

```
<input  type="text" name="prname" required/>
```

the text field it `required` so it validating the form and it doesn't allow the form to submit

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action=<?php echo base_url()."index.php/controller_user/checker"; ?>  >
  <table width="100%" border="0" >
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="prj" >Enter Project:-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input  type="text" name="prname" required/>
              </div>
              <div id="project">Enter Project:-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <select class="prj_name" name="prj_name" id="prj_name" onchange="process(this.value)" tabindex="11" required>
                  <option selected="selected">Select Project</option>
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM project  ORDER BY prj_id DESC";
                    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
                    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
                      foreach ($query->result() as $row){
                        $projectName= $row->prj_name;
                        $projectID=$row->prj_id;
                        echo '<option value="'.$projectID.'">'.$projectName.'</option>';
                      }//end of for loop
                      echo '<option value="'.'0'.'">'.'New Project'.'</option>';
                    } 
                  ?>
                </select>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Comment: what exactly I should do??

Comment: Yes that is the problem :) hope you fixed